# Apply np.subtract to row in pandas skipping nan

Tags: python, pandas, nan, subtraction

I am trying to create a function to operate with basic operations between 2 columns.

So i defined some lambda functions to apply to the dataframes

```
addi=lambda x: np.round(x.sum(),2)
subt=lambda x: np.round(np.subtract.reduce(x.values),2)
prod=lambda x: np.round(x.prod(),2)
divi=lambda x: np.round(np.divide.reduce(x.values),2)
```

In df a new column is created with the result of the operation. Example

```
co = self.df.columns[cn]#columns names
df[new_name] = self.df.loc[:, co].apply(subt,axis=1)
```

There is GUI to select the operation

The thing is that the nan values are not filter out for the subtraction and division, and this may lead to nan values.

I tried to modified this by

```
subt=lambda x: np.round(np.subtract.reduce(np.ma.masked_array(x.values,mask=[np.isnan(x.values)])),2)
```

but i got this error

```
AttributeError: ("'numpy.float64' object has no attribute '_mask'", u'occurred at index 2010-01-27 15:50:00')
```

Comment: You can remove the `NaN` values by doing `x.dropna().values`